# Objective C - How To Keep Reference To Multiple Objects With Keys Just Like How NSMutableDictionary Works

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I just learned how to make use of `KVO`, but only the basics. What I need to achieve is something like this:

I have a delegate call that passes a `Speaker` object.

```
- (void)onSpeakerFound:(Speaker *)speaker
```

Once I receive this `Speaker` in the UI part, from there I will assign observers for this object.

But, this is just for one speaker. What if I have multiple speakers to keep track of. I need to assign observers separately for those speakers and then at the same time I wish to keep their references for further updates to the values.

Each speaker could be updated from time to time. So when I notice that there is a change that happened on a speaker, I wish to access the reference to that speaker and update the values just like how `NSMutableDictionary` works.

`NSMutableDictionary` makes a copy of an object set to it so it will be a difference object if I get it again from the dictionary.

So, is there a class that allows me to keep track of an object by just keeping a reference only to that object without making a copy of it?

EDIT: A Test Made To Verify That When An Instantiated Object is Set in an `NSMutableDictionary`, The Instantiated Object is not referenced with the one set inside `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString *obj = @"initial value";
    NSString *key = @"key";

    [dict setObject:obj forKey:key];

    NSLog(@"Object is now %@", [dict objectForKey:key]);

    obj = @"changed value";

    NSLog(@"Object is now %@", [dict objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Log:

```
2016-07-26 21:04:58.759 AutoLayoutTest[49723:2144268] Object is now initial value
2016-07-26 21:04:58.761 AutoLayoutTest[49723:2144268] Object is now initial value
```

Comment: Could you log `NSLog(@"Adress %p", obj);` after creating it, after getting it back from the dictionary, and then after changing its value? You'll see the difference. Do another test, but with a `NSMutableString` instead for instance replacing characters:  `[(NSMutableString *)obj replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [@"initial" length]) withString:@"replacement"];`

Comment: @Larme Thanks, I just lead myself to confusion with the NSString thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NSMutableDictionary makes a copy of an object set to it...

That is not correct; it will add a *reference* to the object.  It will be the same object referenced inside and outside the Objective-C collection.

> So, is there a class that allows me to keep track of an object...?

Probably `NSMutableSet` if you just want a list of the objects. That will take care that you have a unique reference to each object, however you need to implement the methods `hash` and `isEqual` on those objects so they behave correctly.  Otherwise `NSMutableDictionary` if you want fast look-up by key.

Comment: No, I did a test. I instantiated an object, set it to an NSMutableDictionary. Then I changed the value of that object, then I logged the value of the object that was set to NSMutableDictionary before. The value of that object did not change.

Comment: @JLT Your test is wrong then, I'm afraid.  I stand by my answer.

Comment: You can try it yourself right now to verify whether I am wrong or not.

Comment: I just edited my answer and added the test I did, and also the log.

Comment: @JLT Your test only changes the reference outside of the dictionary.  Re-do it using `NSMutableString` and use `[obj appendString:@" changed"]`.

Comment: Hmm I am confused. Because you just stated in your answer that "It will be the same object referenced inside and outside the Objective-C collection". So, I assume that you mean to say when I change the reference outside. The reference inside NSMutableDictiornary will also be affected. Or I just misunderstood you.

Comment: @JLT No, when you change the reference outside you no longer reference the object within the dictionary.  Don't worry this is the behaviour you want.

Comment: That was my point man when I said that it made a copy of that object. Maybe I just didn't explain my problem well.

Comment: @JLT No your test code demonstrates your confusion.  It's not a copy of the object at all.  You need to test with a mutable object that you can affect  via the external reference and observe the change within the dictionary.  Please retry with `NSMutableString` as I mentioned before and see if that solves your confusion.

Comment: I see, I just did the test and you are right about that. I also did a test with a custom object. Looks like the NSString did really lead me to this confusion. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

-try this one

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString *obj = @"initial value";
    NSString *key = @"key";

    [dict setObject:obj forKey:key];

    NSLog(@"Object is now %@", [dict objectForKey:key]);

    obj = @"changed value";
    [dict setObject:obj forKey:Key];

    NSLog(@"Object is now %@", [dict objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Comment: I know that you have to set it again to update the reference.